Dict comprehension over multiple dicts with missing keys
I have a piece of legacy python2 code that looks like the following
    # dict1 and dict2 are inputs. dict2 is where the value is a 4-tuple
    return {
        key: [
            NamedTuple1(val1, val2, val3, val4),
            NamedTuple2(
                dict2.get(key, (None, None, None, None))[0],
                dict2.get(key, (None, None, None, None))[1],
                dict2.get(key, (None, None, None, None))[2],
                dict2.get(key, (None, None, None, None))[3],
            ),
        ]
        for key, (val1, val2, val3, val4) in dict1.items()
    }

I don't like this code because it does dict2.get(key, (None, None, None, None)) 4x every iteration, and I feel like there should be a simpler way to write this. Is there a way to put the dict2 in the for loop and for missing key, just return a (None, None, None, None) and then unwrap this within NamedTuple2?

Can you provide sample data for dict1 and dict2 so that it becomes reproducible?

I think you should be able to use argument unpacking in this particular example. The only assumption is every value in dict2 needs to be 4 items long.
# dict1 and dict2 are inputs. dict2 is where the value is a 4-tuple
return {
    key: [
        NamedTuple1(val1, val2, val3, val4),
        NamedTuple2(*dict2.get(key, (None, None, None, None))),
    ]
    for key, (val1, val2, val3, val4) in dict1.items()
}

If that doesn't work for you, then I suggest to extract part of the comprehesion into a function:
# dict1 and dict2 are inputs. dict2 is where the value is a 4-tuple
return {
    key: extract_value(dict2, key, val1, val2, val3, val4)
    for key, (val1, val2, val3, val4) in dict1.items()
}
....
def extract_key(dict2, key, val1, val2, val3, val4):
    dict2value = dict2.get(key, (None, None, None, None))
    return [
        NamedTuple1(val1, val2, val3, val4),
        NamedTuple2(
            dict2value[0],
            dict2value[1],
            dict2value[2],
            dict2value[3],
        ),
    ]


Oh neat, I wasn't aware of argument unpacking (not much of a python dev). the first one works and it also seems compatible with py3 (my understanding is this codebase I'm using will deprecate py2 soon)

It is possible to simply do "star-unpacking" in the  call to NamedTuple2:
    # dict1 and dict2 are inputs. dict2 is where the value is a 4-tuple
    return {
        key: [
            NamedTuple1(val1, val2, val3, val4),
            NamedTuple2(
                *dict2.get(key, (None, None, None, None))
            ),
        ]
        for key, (val1, val2, val3, val4) in dict1.items()
    }

